# Header image with .NET Core and bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, header, .net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm starting to learn code in .net core 2.0 and as the first application I decided to write a simple blog system. I encountered a problem when i wanted put different header background image to the each post details page and the main one on index page. Image is passing by ViewData["Image"] to the _Layout. I tried to put the same image to the both views Index and Details but image displays only on Index page.

Index View

```
@model PaginatedList<MHBlog.Models.Post>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    ViewData["Image"] = "11.jpg";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
```

Details View

```
@model MHBlog.Models.Post
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    ViewData["Image"] = Model.ImageName;
}
<h2>Details</h2>
```

_Layout

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url(images/@ViewData["Image"])">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <h1>Blog</h1>
                    <span class="subheading">My First Blog</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #777777;
  background-attachment: scroll;  
}
header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .post-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading {
  padding: 200px 0 150px;
  color: white; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header.masthead .page-heading,
  header.masthead .post-heading,
  header.masthead .site-heading {
    padding: 200px 0; } }
header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading,
header.masthead .post-heading{
  text-align: center;
}
header.masthead .page-heading h1,
header.masthead .site-heading h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 0; }
header.masthead .page-heading .subheading,
header.masthead .site-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header.masthead .page-heading h1,
  header.masthead .site-heading h1 {
    font-size: 80px; } }
header.masthead .post-heading h1 {
  font-size: 35px; }
header.masthead .post-heading .meta,
header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
  line-height: 1.1;
  display: block; }
header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
header.masthead .post-heading .meta {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Times New Roman', serif; }
header.masthead .post-heading .meta a {
  color: white; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header.masthead .post-heading h1 {
    font-size: 55px; }
header.masthead .post-heading .subheading {
  font-size: 30px; } }
```

Index page:

[image]

Details page:

[image]

I tried to set details ViewData Image to 
    @ViewData["Image"] = "11.jpg"

But nothing changed on details page.

Comment: Where is the images? wwwroot > images folder or different location?

Comment: Yes, in wwwroot/images/,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that `style="background-image:url('/images/@ViewData["Image"]')"`.

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image:url('/images/@ViewData["Image"]')">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="post-heading">
                <h1>Blog</h1>
                <span class="subheading">My First Blog</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works.. The problem was / before the path. I thought that if it works on index page 
then there is not syntax error here. Thanks!